# How do you include a 3rd party npm in apostrophe-cms?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I want to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-parser in apostrophe cms. Where do I add the var youTubeParser = require('youtube-parser'); so I can access if from a widget's always.js file

Answer (score 0):

`youtube-parser` seems to be a node module. `always.js` is a browser side javascript file, you can't use youtube-parser in this file.

However, you can do on server side, in your widget index.js file.

```
var youtubeParser = require('youtube-parser');
// in lib/modules/your-widgets/index.js

module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  addFields: [
    // widget's fields
  ],
  construct: function(self, options) {
    // Override output function to pass some vars to the widget.html template
    self.output = function(widget, options) {
      // Here your youtube parsing stuff
      // Store your result on widget property
      widget.youtuberesult = {};
      var result = self.partial(self.template, { widget: widget, options: options, manager: self });
      return result;
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: You have a typo in the first line, that should be "var", not "require" at the start of the line.

Also, depending on what he really wants to do he might need to do this where async code is allowed, such as in the `load` method, or via a route the player calls back to to avoid blocking page rendering while waiting for YouTube.